# Updating List in Sharepoint Online (o365) via Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-online

I am currently using VBA to update/create new sharepoint list items via SOAP.

My IT dept has advised that they are migrating to SharePoint Online and the same code no longer works, I believe due to different authentication processes.

I have spent close to four days trying to find an alternative solution for o365 via VBA but unfortunately I'm not having much luck.

I am hoping that there is someone out there that may be able to assist, I've included my original VBA/SOAP code as a reference for what I'm trying to replicate.

Many thanks,
Riss

```
Sub addItemtoList()

    Dim LISTNAME As String
    Dim SharepointUrl As String
    Dim ValueVar As String
    Dim FieldNameVar As String
    Dim CurUserName As String, CurPassword As String
    CurUserName = "user.name"
    CurPassword = "password123"

    LISTNAME = "SharepointlistName"      'Or Guild

    SharepointUrl = "https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/au/finance/xxxxxx/"
    ValueVar = "Testing Value Add"
    FieldNameVar = "'Title'"

    Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    Dim strListNameOrGuid As String
    Dim strBatchXml As String
    Dim strSoapBody As String

    Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    strListNameOrGuid = LISTNAME


    'Add New Item'
    strBatchXml = "<Batch OnError='Continue'><Method ID='1' Cmd='New'><Field Name='ID'>New</Field><Field Name=" + FieldNameVar + ">" + ValueVar + "</Field></Method></Batch>"

    objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", SharepointUrl + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", False, CurUserName, CurPassword
    objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
    objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"

    strSoapBody = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " _
     & "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " _
     & "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><UpdateListItems " _
     & "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>" & strListNameOrGuid _
     & "</listName><updates>" & strBatchXml & "</updates></UpdateListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

    objXMLHTTP.send strSoapBody

    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    ' Do something with response
    End If

    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: You might get a faster response asking this on [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Okay, thanks.. will do.

Comment: Hey, did you have an answer on this question ? Having same challenge now. Thanks !